# docker environment, can't access webcam

Tags: c++, docker, opencv, webcam

Trying to capture some frames with a USB camera. I'm using Docker so this application is containerized, but I have mapped /dev/ttyUSB0 correctly, so inside the container I am able to communicate (via serial commands) to the camera with no issue.

My current issue stems from my attempt at capturing frames using OpenCV.

In my capture function, I have:

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

std::string filename;
std::string file_extension = "mp4";

SPDLOG_INFO("Creating video capture filename.");
create_filename(filename, capture_sequence_number, file_extension);

// Create a VideoCapture object.
VideoCapture cap("/dev/ttyUSB0");
        
// Check if camera opened successfully
if(!cap.isOpened()){
    SPDLOG_ERROR("Failed to open video stream.");
    return;
}
```

The isOpened() is returning false, as the "Failed to open video stream" log statement is printed, and none of the subsequent capturing code executes.

Is there a decent way to diagnose this? I can preview the camera (using some hardware I have here), so I know it is outputting frames, and I can communicate with it over serial, so I know it's connected within the container (communicating via /dev/ttyUSB0). I am just not sure how to go about diagnosing why the VideoCapture object is not opening. My camera is connected to a CameraLink to GigE converter, I have an ethernet cord from that GigE converter into my laptop, so I'm not sure if there's potentially some networking aspect I'm missing?

Comment: `/dev/ttyUSB0` is a serial port.  It is not a camera.  OpenCV is not going to recognize it.  EXACTLY what kind of camera is this?

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. I have tried with using indexes in the constructor instead, I tried 0, 1 and -1, but still the same result, so I tried the /dev/ttyUSB0 as a hail mary. The camera is https://www.photonis.com/products/nocturn-xl and the CL-GigE converter is https://www.pleora.com/machine-vision-automation/iport-cl-gige/

Comment: test with `guvcview` or VLC or ffmpeg. OpenCV wants cameras that show up as `/dev/video0` or something like that. USB devices do not commonly do "GigE Vision" (which is Ethernet-based).

Comment: That's not a USB camera!  That a GigE Vision camera -- it delivers video over Ethernet.  Where are you getting a USB connection?  You just need to know the IP address where it can be reached.

Comment: Hmmm yeah I suppose you’re right. I guess I was just using serial to communicate with the camera and incorrectly assumed I would capture over usb too. I have checked the spec sheet and  couldn’t find any IP address nor a way to configure it..

Comment: OK nevermind, I should be using the SDK that comes with the converter to capture frames